# What is the purpose and functioning of check(3rd Argument) in std::sort()?

Tags: c++, sorting

This is program of sorting big integers in string.
So there is a function check

```
bool check(string str1, string str2)
{
    int n1 = str1.length(), n2 = str2.length();

    if (n1 < n2)
       return true;
    if (n2 < n1)
       return false;
    for (int i=0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] < str2[i])
            return true;
        if (str1[i] > str2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and the main function is:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<string> s;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        string s1;
        cin>>s1;
        s.push_back(s1);
    }

    sort(s.begin(),s.end(),check);
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        cout<< s[i] <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input:**

> 6
>   31415926535897932384626433832795
>   1
>   3
>   10
>   3
>   5

**Sample Output**

> 1
>   3
>   3
>   5
>   10
>   31415926535897932384626433832795

I want to know how this check function works, which numbers are passed first? How it affects the code when it returns true or false?

Comment: The function is used to compare elements of the array or vector that is being sorted.

Comment: `check` is a misleading name. `less_by_lenght_then_lexicography`/`my_less`/`my_compare` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument is the comparison function.

First it checks the argument length, and returns true if the first is shorter than the second, false if the second is shorter than the first. 
Then if the two strings are of equal length it compares the two strings character by character and returns true if a char from the first compares less than the char from the second, false if the char from the second compares less than the char from the first.
 Finally it returns false if the two strings are equal because the comparison needs to implement a strictly less-than ordering.

Comment: And what after getting true or false?? sort( arr , arr+n , check(true/false) ) what will happen next?

Comment: @djmayank - The array will be sorted based on the result. `std::sort` uses `<` if you don't supply a third argument, no other difference.

Answer (score 3):

The `check` function is used as a comparator in `std::sort` (in other words `std::sort` calls `check` when it needs to compare elements).

> The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first
>   argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict
>   weak ordering it defines

This function compares the length of the numbers (considering there are no leading zeroes in the numbers), then if these numbers have the same length it compares numbers themselves. This function can be shortened:

```
bool check(const string& str1, const string& str2)
{
    int len1 = str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();
    return std::tie(len1, str1) < std::tie(len2, str2);
}
```